# How To Check Quality Gate Status with official Github Action

Tags: github, sonarqube, github-actions

Good Day everyone,

I would like to know how to check the quality gate status from a previous scan in a gitHub workflow.

Im using serverVersion=9.4.0.54424 and using the scan with the Msbuild tool (SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe)

In my workflow I was able to checkout my repo, trigger scan, succeed the scan but the part for check the quality Gate always fails.

My github runner its running over a windows server and Im using the official git action to check the quality status from the previous step in the workflow

When it tries to check the quality gate it always fails with this error:

```
Run sonarsource/sonarqube-quality-gate-action@master

check_suite_focus=true#step:4:6) Error: bash: command not found
```

It comes to my mind that because Im running the workflow in a windows runner its fails because it cant find the “bash” not sure if the official github actions for checking the quality gate its not mean to be ran in a Windows Servers.

This is the actions im trying to use to check the quality Gate:
(GitHub - SonarSource/sonarqube-quality-gate-action)

We use Github Enterprise in our own servers and we have another server for the github runners.

I was able to succeed the scan from the pipeline and the check the report in sonarqube dashboard (sonarqube its in our own server too) but in the step for checking the quality gate that its fails.

this is the whole workflow yml im using:

```
on:
  # Trigger analysis when pushing in master or pull requests, and when creating
  # a pull request. 
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
      types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]
name: Quality Gate Check
jobs:
  sonarqube:
    runs-on: [self-hosted]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        # Disabling shallow clone is recommended for improving relevancy of reporting.
        fetch-depth: 0

    # Triggering SonarQube analysis as results of it are required by Quality Gate check.
    - name: SonarQube Scan
      env:
        SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.US_SONAR_TOKEN }}
        SONAR_HOST_URL: https://sonarqube.host.com
      run: |
        $sonarscanner = (Get-Command "SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe").Path
        $msbuild = (Get-Command "msbuild.exe").Path
        write-host "GITHUB_WORKSPACE " $env:GITHUB_WORKSPACE
        $env:SONAR_HOST_URL
        $env:SONAR_TOKEN
        & "\\somehost.com\dev_repo\Dev_Repo\BuildTools\NuGet\nuget.exe" restore "$env:GITHUB_WORKSPACE\project.sln"
        & $sonarscanner begin /key:projectkey  "/d:sonar.host.url=`"$env:SONAR_HOST_URL`"" "/d:sonar.login=`"$env:SONAR_TOKEN`""
        & $msbuild  /p:Configuration=Release /p:DefineConstants="US" /p:Platform="AnyCPU" /p:publishUrl="E:\Github.runner\build_output\" /p:OutDir="E:\Github.runner\build_output\" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:langversion=8.0 /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=true /p:PipelineDependsOnBuild=false -maxcpucount:4 "$env:GITHUB_WORKSPACE\project.csproj"
        & $sonarscanner  end "/d:sonar.login=`"$env:SONAR_TOKEN`""

    # Check the Quality Gate status.
    - name: SonarQube Quality Gate check
      id: sonarqube-quality-gate-check
      uses: sonarsource/sonarqube-quality-gate-action@master
      with:
        scanMetadataReportFile: .sonarqube\out\.sonar\report-task.txt
      # Force to fail step after specific time.
      timeout-minutes: 5

    # Optionally you can use the output from the Quality Gate in another step.
    # The possible outputs of the `quality-gate-status` variable are `PASSED`, `WARN` or `FAILED`.
    - name: "Example show SonarQube Quality Gate Status value"
      run: echo "The Quality Gate status is ${{ steps.sonarqube-quality-gate-check.outputs.quality-gate-status }}"
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant parts of the workflow? On a `run` step, you can [specify which shell to use](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-running-a-script-using-bash), so even on Windows runners you can have Bash with `shell: bash`.

Comment: sure, I edited the post to add the workflow yml, thanks